# Merge collection of nested array elements into one array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to merge a collection of nested array elements into one array.

Array:

```
crop_data = [
                [
                    ["crop" => "soy"]   // 0
                ],

                [
                    ["crop" => "rye"]   // 1
                ],

                [
                    ["crop" => "tree"]  // 2
                ]
            ],

            [
                [
                    ["crop" => "salt"]  // 0
                ],

                [
                    ["crop" => "farm"]  // 1
                ]
            ],

            [
                [
                    ["year" => "2015"]
                ]
            ]
```

I've tried the following...

```
$crop_data = array();   // new array

foreach($crop_list as $value) {
    $crop_data = array_merge($value, $crop_list));
}
```

I would like to merge the inner elements of the three arrays into one array. Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: 1) Have you tried something ? 2) What is your expected output?

Comment: writing code would would be a good start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) for this.

```
$merged = array();
array_walk_recursive($crop_data, function($v, $k) use (&$merged) {
    $merged[$k][] = $v;
});
```